# Performance tuning in F# scripts / F# interactive

Tags: .net, performance, f#, profiling, f#-interactive

I need to convert an arbitrary integer (that is, `bigint`) into its digits, so I can access them by index.

I found myself wo(a)ndering, though, between two possible implementations of the algorithm:

```
open System

let toDigits (x:bigint) =
    x.ToString() 
    |> Seq.map (fun c -> (int c) - (int '0'))
    |> Seq.toArray

let toDigits' (x:bigint) =
    seq {
        let x' = ref x
        while !x' <> 0I do
            yield (int (!x' % 10I))
            x' := !x' / 10I
    } |> Seq.toArray |> Seq.rev
```

Which one is fastest I mumbled? To help me answer the question, I devised a simple `profile` method

```
let profile f times = 
    let x = ref 0
    while !x < times do
        incr x
        f (bigint !x) |> ignore
```

that when conflated with F# Interactive's `#time` yielded the following output:

```
> profile toDigits 10000000;;
Real: 00:00:11.609, CPU: 00:00:11.606, GC gen0: 825, gen1: 1, gen2: 0
val it : unit = ()
> profile toDigits' 10000000;;
Real: 00:00:28.891, CPU: 00:00:28.844, GC gen0: 1639, gen1: 3, gen2: 0
val it : unit = ()
```

This clearly showed `toDigit`'s superiority. I'd like to know why, though, so I'm asking my fellow F# overflowers what should I do from this point on.

In a typical Java program I'd just fire up a profiler (jvisualvm, for instance) and have it tell me which were the hot methods in some kind of CPU Sampling view. I guess this would work exactly the same way were I developing with .fs files in a regular project. As I'm in F# Interactive I'm a bit lost. Should I attach the .NET profiler (in this case, ANTS Memory Profiler) to F# Interactive? Is there any special workflow for this kind of software development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a typical Java program I'd just fire up a profiler (jvisualvm, for instance) and have it tell me which were the hot methods in some kind of CPU Sampling view. I guess this would work exactly the same way were I developing with .fs files in a regular project. As I'm in F# Interactive I'm a bit lost.

Using `fsx` files and F# Interactive doesn't mean that you should abandon compiling projects completely. I would change `Build Action` in `File Properties` to `Compile` in order to compile fsx files directly. We need to use conditional compilation at some places e.g.

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#time "on";;
#endif
```

The advantages of compiling the code are:

- You can use Visual Studio profilers to get statistics about hot spots in programs.
- You can decompile programs using ILSpy. Sometimes ILs or even equivalent C# code can give you insights on how the programs behave.

As the code evolves, you can consider moving core functions to `fs` files and keep quick profiling functions in `fsx` files.

Back to your example, an improvement of `toDigits'` is to avoid using references:

```
let toDigits'' (x:bigint) =
    let rec loop x acc =
        if x <> 0I then
            loop (x/10I) (int(x%10I)::acc)
        else acc
    loop x [] |> List.toArray
```

Results show that `toDigits''` is 1.5x faster than `toDigits'` and 1.5x slower than `toDigits`.

It's hard to beat `toDigit` since it doesn't use any arithmetic operations on `bigint`. One obvious drawback of `toDigit` is that it gives meaningless results on negative `bigint`s.

Comment: Just to make sure: I won't have any advantage in having my code be compiled as a standard .fs file in a regular build as opposed to have it be run through F# Interactive, right? F# Interactive is always going to compile the code I'm passing it anyway, so the performance will be exactly the same.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this is not the answer you were looking for, but in the world of functional programming the choice of right means (algorithm, data structures, ...) for the task may bring **much more** benefits, than whatever thorough OOP-like micro-level code analysis a .NET profiler may give.

To illustrate my point, in your demo cases the choice to operate with **sequences** in both `toDigits` and `toDigits'` functions is hard to justify. If we choose instead to stay within **array** space, than equivalent functionality can be expressed as

```
let toDigits'' (x: bigint) =
    x.ToString().ToCharArray() |> Array.map (fun c -> int(c) - int('0'))
```

Turning now to FSI-provided profiling we can observe

```
> profile toDigits 10000000;;
Real: 00:00:13.020, CPU: 00:00:13.000, GC gen0: 1649, gen1: 2, gen2: 0

> profile toDigits'' 10000000;;
Real: 00:00:02.334, CPU: 00:00:02.343, GC gen0: 604, gen1: 1, gen2: 0
```

So, we got **5.6 times speedup** just due to a better choice of data structures to operate upon and FSI profiler serves just as a **confirmation** of this fact.

Comment: Very insightful answer :), although as you already noted, is not really an answer to my (central) question. In this post I am particularly concerned with the pro's usual workflow when developing algorithms in F# / F# Interactive, not so much with a good algorithm implementation per se.

Comment: I bothered with answering exactly for the purpose of pointing out that pro's workflows for OOP and FP may quite differ. Cases take place when I want to see F#-generated IL, but these happen so-o-o infrequently...

Comment: This is the best answer, as it points out that you should revise your usual OOP workflows when working with F#.